# Binary search tree insert method not working python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

This is my code for my binary search tree implementation:

```
class Tree(Node):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
    def find(self, data, root):
        if root == None:
            return False
        wanderer = root
        if data == wanderer.data:
            return True
        elif data > wanderer.data:
            return self.find(data, root.right)
        else:
            return self.find(data, root.left)
        return False
    def insert(self, data, root):
        if root == None:
            root = Node(data)
            return True
        if data > root.data:
            return self.insert(data, root.right)
        elif data < root.data:
            return self.insert(data, root.left)
        else:
            return False
```

My insert method doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out what is wrong with it. Please help.

Comment: Assigning to new value to `root` does not change what `root` pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

`root = Node(data)` does **not** assign the new node back to the caller argument `root.right` or `root.left`.

See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html for more details.